# Set object set by code in Mockery

Tags: php, phpunit, mockery

I've following code to be tested.

```
// $generator, $locale, $site are parameters.
// It is just a part of real code.
$text = new Text();
$text->setType($generator->getType())
    ->setLocale($locale)
    ->setSite($site->getId());

/** @var $site \namespace\Site */
$site->addText($text);
```

To test this, I'm making mock of Site using Mockery.

In test, I generally want to do

```
$text = $site->getText();
$this->assertInstanceOF('\namespace\Text', $text);
$this->assertSame($generator->getType(), $text->getType());
$this->assertSame($locale, $text->getLocale());
$this->assertSame($site->getId(), $text->getSite());
```

While making mock, I want mock to return the instance of Text created by original code and set in line `$site->addText($site)`. I tried

```
$text = new Text();
$site = Mockery::mock(Site::class)
    ->shouldReceive('addText')
    ->with($text)
    ->andReturnUsing(function() {
            $args = func_get_args();
            return $args[0];
        })
    ->getMock();
```

This return me object of Text set in mocking code. In mockery, is there any way I can get Text object created in original code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Mockery::on()` method in this case. Refer to the [argument validation docs](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/argument_validation.html) . Here you can pass a closure which receives the argument passed to the addText method. You can also use PHPUnit assertions in this closure to do assertions on the `$text` parameter.
Like this:

```
$site = Mockery::mock(Site::class)
    ->shouldReceive('addText')
    ->with(Mockery::on(function($text) {
        $this->assertInstanceOF('\namespace\Text', $text);
        //More assertions

        return true; //You must return true, otherwise the expectation will never pass regardless of the assertions above.
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks @bram, I'd similar problem, and solution you gave seems best fit for my problem.